# resize browser with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Is it possible to resize the browser window with puppeteer? I know there is `page.setViewport`, but is there anything like `browser.setViewport`? Maybe it sounds like there isn't much difference if you're running the headless version, but it can be useful if you're actually displaying the window, I'd like to do something like this:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
});
await browser.setViewport({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
});
})();
```

Answer (score 15):

What I've found works for setting the browser size (but not the viewport size) is to set the following chrome command line switch when you're launching puppeteer:

```
await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  args: [
    '--window-size=X,Y'
  ]
});
```

All you have to do is substitute whatever resolution settings you want into the code instead of the X (width) and Y (height).

**Update:**
I've since located the following issue in which someone, rather helpfully, has provided their own `resizeWindow()` function which, apparently, does what you need. I've not tried it out so can't vouch for whether it works or not but it might be worth a try!

https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/issues/973

Comment: That's good enough for my current needs, but it would be nice to be able to programmatically manipulate the window size after launching the browser. I think there's no support for that yet.

Comment: It's not a built in function, unfortunately. I have added a link to my original answer in which someone provides their own `resizeWindow()` function which, apparently, does this very thing. I've not tried it, personally, but you might find it interesting!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No**, you cannot resize

[This](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-browser) is everything you can do on a `browser`:

- `browser.browserContexts()`
- `browser.close()`
- `browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext()`
- `browser.disconnect()`
- `browser.newPage()`
- `browser.pages()`
- `browser.process()`
- `browser.targets()`
- `browser.userAgent()`
- `browser.version()`
- `browser.wsEndpoint()`

And it emits these events:

- event: `'disconnected'`
- event: `'targetchanged'`
- event: `'targetcreated'`
- event: `'targetdestroyed'`

Resizing is not on the list. Maybe you could try creating a feature request.